# Does this product of ratios always result in an integer?

Tags: number-theory

Claim: the product:
$$ \prod_{(i,j)\in [N]^2, i\neq j} \dfrac{m_j-m_i}{j-i}$$ is an integer if the set $\{m_k\}$ are all integers, where $1 \le k\le N$ (i.e. $k\in [N]$).

And if not please give a counter example. Thank you.

Here is an incomplete attempt:
At least $N-2$ pairs must differ by a multiple of $2$ by a pigeon hole argument: fix an even and an odd one say (if they’re all even or all odd then it works even more easily), then the remaining $N-2$ numbers must be equal to one of these mod $2$ since $0$ and $1$ are the only possible remainders. Similarly at least $N-3$ pairs must differ by a multiple of $3$, etc. Then the denominator cancels.

Comment: You need the $m_i$ to be distinct. Hint: Vandermonde. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105348/showing-prod-limits-ij-fracx-i-x-ji-j-is-an-integer) for the solution.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the m?

Comment: The m_i need not be distinct - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.